# Not Serializable Exception for class that implements serializable

Tags: java, android, serialization, ioexception

I have the following class:

```
public class NightPoint implements Serializable
    {
        Date time;
        int y;

        public NightPoint(){};

        public NightPoint(Date time, int y)
        {
            this.time = time;
            this.y = y;
        }
    }
```

But when I try to do the following I get NotSerializableException:

```
try {
            FileOutputStream fos = act.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            os.writeObject(np);
            os.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("Output", "Write: IOException -->" + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I have check to make sure that Date is serializable and it is, so I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong...

```
10-12 17:10:05.542: W/System.err(7330): java.io.NotSerializableException: com.SPTechnos.sleepsmart.Main
10-12 17:10:05.542: W/System.err(7330):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1364)
10-12 17:10:05.542: W/System.err(7330):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
10-12 17:10:05.542: W/System.err(7330):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
10-12 17:10:05.542: W/System.err(7330):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
10-12 17:10:05.542: W/System.err(7330):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:979)
10-12 17:10:05.542: W/System.err(7330):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:368)
10-12 17:10:05.542: W/System.err(7330):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1074)
10-12 17:10:05.542: W/System.err(7330):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1404)
10-12 17:10:05.542: W/System.err(7330):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
10-12 17:10:05.542: W/System.err(7330):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
10-12 17:10:05.542: W/System.err(7330):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
10-12 17:10:05.542: W/System.err(7330):     at com.SPTechnos.sleepsmart.FileLogger.writeNP(FileLogger.java:34)
10-12 17:10:05.542: W/System.err(7330):     at com.SPTechnos.sleepsmart.Main.onCreate(Main.java:50)
10-12 17:10:05.542: W/System.err(7330):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
10-12 17:10:05.542: W/System.err(7330):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
10-12 17:10:05.542: W/System.err(7330):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
10-12 17:10:05.542: W/System.err(7330):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
10-12 17:10:05.542: W/System.err(7330):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
10-12 17:10:05.552: W/System.err(7330):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
10-12 17:10:05.552: W/System.err(7330):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-12 17:10:05.552: W/System.err(7330):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
10-12 17:10:05.552: W/System.err(7330):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
10-12 17:10:05.552: W/System.err(7330):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-12 17:10:05.552: W/System.err(7330):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-12 17:10:05.552: W/System.err(7330):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
10-12 17:10:05.552: W/System.err(7330):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
10-12 17:10:05.552: W/System.err(7330):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Have you imported `java.sql.Date` instead of `java.util.Date`?

Comment: I am importing java.util.Date

Comment: Please post the exception stacktrace.

Comment: It is the `Main` class that isn't serializable. Do read the exception message. It contradicts your title.

Comment: But I am not writing the Main class... So why does it need to be serializable?  I am writing the NightPoint class

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the problem was stemming from the fact that I made the class "NightPoint" inside the class "Main"; however, simply moving it to its only File solved the problem.

Comment: For more, read about the difference between "inner class" and "static inner class"

Comment: @laalto 'Static inner class' is a contradiction in terms. A nested class can be inner or static, not both.

Comment: The 'some reason' is that an instance of an inner class retains a reference to the enclosing object, in this case an instance of `Main`, which isn't `Serializable`.